# Efficiently group rows into episodes without PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, gaps-and-islands

I have a dataset with one record per day per entity. Each day will only ever have one status but a status can appear over a range of days or only on a single day

What I want to do is group these into episodes. So whenever the ID changes, the STATUS changes OR the next record is more than a day apart I want to consider it a new episode.

I have played around with analytic functions but while I can group by status I then loose track of each set of days (though potentially I could do it in one pass per status)

I also could do this in PL/SQL but it's incredibly slow in my testing. I'm hoping there is a way to perform this as a query or at least partially pre-process as a query so the pl/sql loop is faster.

```
ID                      DAY         STATUS  Comment
E0000000000054245349    27-Feb-16   24      Start
E0000000000054245349    28-Feb-16   24  
E0000000000054245349    29-Feb-16   24  
E0000000000054245349    1-Mar-16    24  
E0000000000054245349    3-Mar-16    21      Gap & new status
E0000000000054245349    4-Mar-16    21  
            continuing daily
E0000000000054245349    12-Mar-16   21  
E0000000000054245349    13-Mar-16   21  
E0000000000054245349    14-Mar-16   21  
E0000000000054245349    15-Mar-16   40      No gap, but new status
E0000000000054245349    16-Mar-16   40  
E0000000000054245349    18-Mar-16   40      Gap, no new status
E0000000000054245349    19-Mar-16   40      
E0000000000054245349    1-Jan-17    21      Gap & new status
E0000000000054245349    2-Jan-17    21
E0000000000054245349    3-Jan-17    21      
E0000000000054245349    5-Jan-17    25      Gap, status and single day
```

My ideal dataset would like something like this. Bonus points if it contains the previous/next status for records that are 1 day before/after but I can always get them with a subsequent query if need be

```
ID                      START       END         STATUS
E0000000000054245349    27-Feb-16   1-Mar-16    24
E0000000000054245349    3-Mar-16    14-Mar-16   21
E0000000000054245349    15-Mar-16   16-Mar-16   40
E0000000000054245349    18-Mar-16   19-Mar-16   40
E0000000000054245349    1-Jan-17    3-Jan-17    21
E0000000000054245349    5-Jan-17    5-Jan-17    25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it easily using [Tabibitosan Method](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680):

```
select id, min(day) mnd, max(day) mxd, status
  from (
    select day - row_number() over (partition by id order by day) grp, id, day, status
      from t)
  group by id, grp, status
  order by id, grp;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eac6311924e8dc0f2f28e6a91a95235b)</sup>**

This gives desirded output. I do not catch that phrase *Bonus points if it contains the previous/next status for records that are 1 day before/after*. In your output episodes may have no rows one day before / after. If you want status from previous / next row simply use `lag()` and `lead ()`. But if you want it **only** if new episode is because of status change use analytical functions conditionally:

```
select id, mnd, mxd, status, 
       case mnd when lag(mxd) over (partition by id order by mxd) + 1
                then lag(status) over (partition by id order by mxd) 
       end prev_status
  from (select id, min(day) mnd, max(day) mxd, status
          from (select day - row_number() over (partition by id order by day) grp, 
                       id, day, status
                  from t)
          group by id, grp, status)
  order by id, mnd;
```

... and same for `lead()`.

Comment: Actually, I just found an issue with this.. the partition needs the id and the status, otherwise where the days are contiguous but the status is not they are considered the same group

Answer (score 1):

This is a gap & island problem - you can try in below way

```
select id, status,min(DAY) start,max(DAY) end
from
(
select *,island=row_number() over(partition by id order by day) - 
row_number() over(partition by id, status order by day) 
from tablename
)A group by id, status,island
```

Comment: Sorry, the status values can come back days or months later. I've tried to clarify the example and include single-day values